# How to send report in in scheduled time

Tags: laravel-5, scheduling

In laravel 5.8 I have a report with a button “Send Email” by clicking on this button ajax request is run, with content of a report
in “report_html” var to control like:

```
public function sentReportEmailContent()
{
    $request= request();
    $requestData= $request->all();

    $report_html= $requestData['report_html'];

    $loggedUser= Auth::user();

    $reportAvailableSpacesByZonesAcceptorsArray = config('app.reportAvailableSpacesByZonesAcceptorsArray', []);
    $site_name                                  = config('app.name', '');
    if ( count($reportAvailableSpacesByZonesAcceptorsArray) == 0 ) {
        return response()->json(['error_code' => 1, 'message' => 'There are no receiver emails specified !'], HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    $to= $reportAvailableSpacesByZonesAcceptorsArray[0];
    $subject= 'Available Spaces By Zones report was sent at ' . $site_name;
    $additiveVars= [ 'html'=> $report_html ];

    unset($reportAvailableSpacesByZonesAcceptorsArray[0]);
    $cc= $reportAvailableSpacesByZonesAcceptorsArray;
    \Mail::to($to)->send( new SendgridMail( 'emailContainer', $to, $cc, $subject , $additiveVars ) );

    return response()->json(['error_code' => 0, 'message' => '', 'user'=> $loggedUser->id], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
}
```

and with Sendgrid service report is sent to users defined in config ok.

Now I need to run this report and send email to recievers in scheduler.

I created a new command :

```
php artisan make:command reportAvailableSpacesByZones  --command=report:available-spaces-by-zones
```

which has handle method:

```
public function handle()
{
    \Log::info( 'Report run # ' . time()  );
}
```

which is triggered in scheduled time.
But how can I run my report and sent it's content like it is done manually ?

**Modified block :**
My report is run by (local )url :
http://local-boxbooking2.com/admin/report/available-spaces-by-zones
I remade so that if to run url 
http://local-boxbooking2.com/admin/report/available-spaces-by-zones/send-email-on-open

in browser report is opened and checking “send-email-on-open” javascript function is triggered to sent by 
email (with Sendgrid service ) content of the page(report actually)

I tried to trigger command by cron tasks :
In app/Console/Commands/reportAvailableSpacesByZones.php :

```
class reportAvailableSpacesByZones extends Command
{
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::info( 'Report From inside app/Console/Commands/reportAvailableSpacesByZones.php run # ' . time()  );
        return redirect()->to('/admin/report/available-spaces-by-zones/send-email-on-open');
    }
```

I see log info , but no reports by email.
Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app/Console/Kernal.php add the command to the protected commands array

```
 'App\Console\Commands\reportAvailableSpacesByZones',
```

in the scheudle method add

```
  $schedule->command('cron:reportAvailableSpacesByZones')->weeklyOn(2, '20:30');
```

other commands available

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

on the server crontab

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Please, look at Modified block